# How to organize app storage dir support for all devices

Tags: android

I am  building app which works offline, it needs 5mb space for data storage. My problem is how to make it support devices having large internal storage and devices having low internal storage with sd card support. **How to store and retrieve the data.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you answer the question yourself. You need to save it in the SD Card. For more information, look at here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref